# Counting number of object visits per day in django

Tags: django

I have a model like below

```
class Watched(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=None)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Each time an object is viewed, the count attribute will increase by 1.

My problem is how to find the number of times an object was hit per day. How can I achieve this.

The `Stamping` is another model with `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: What do you mean by an object is "viewed", do you mean to count every time the object is retrieved from the database?

Comment: My aim is to return the number of times ```Watched``` was hit per day. Example ```today_so_far = 30```. Here, 30 is the number of times ```Watched``` model has been hit today

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding custom methods either in the model itself or in the model's manager. Here, I added a custom method `visit()` which upon retrieval of the target objects would also increment their counts.

- This should be preferred over the option to override the existing methods e.g. `filter()` and `get()` to not affect those default functionalities. The custom method could be used explicitly for the purpose of retrieval of objects with updates in the count.

```
from django.db import models


class WatchedManager(models.Manager):
    def visit(self, *args, **kwargs):  # Behaves like QuerySet.filter()
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
        qs.update(count=models.F('count') + 1)
        return qs


class Watched(models.Model):
    objects = WatchedManager()

    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

First, let's list all objects

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> from my_app.models import Watched
>>> 
>>> Watched.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Watched: Watched object (1)>, <Watched: Watched object (2)>, <Watched: Watched object (3)>, <Watched: Watched object (4)>, <Watched: Watched object (5)>, <Watched: Watched object (6)>]>
>>> Watched.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'user': 'One', 'count': 0}, {'id': 2, 'user': 'Two', 'count': 0}, {'id': 3, 'user': 'Three', 'count': 0}, {'id': 4, 'user': 'Four', 'count': 0}, {'id': 5, 'user': 'Five', 'count': 0}, {'id': 6, 'user': 'Six', 'count': 0}]>
```

We have 6 objects named from `"One"` to `"Six"`, all with initial count of `0`. Now let's try to visit the names that end with `"e"` which are namely `"One"`, `"Three"`, and `"Five"`.

```
>>> result = Watched.objects.visit(user__endswith='e')
>>> result
<QuerySet [<Watched: Watched object (1)>, <Watched: Watched object (3)>, <Watched: Watched object (5)>]>
>>> result.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'user': 'One', 'count': 1}, {'id': 3, 'user': 'Three', 'count': 1}, {'id': 5, 'user': 'Five', 'count': 1}]>
>>> Watched.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'user': 'One', 'count': 1}, {'id': 2, 'user': 'Two', 'count': 0}, {'id': 3, 'user': 'Three', 'count': 1}, {'id': 4, 'user': 'Four', 'count': 0}, {'id': 5, 'user': 'Five', 'count': 1}, {'id': 6, 'user': 'Six', 'count': 0}]>
```

As you may notice, all their counts automatically increased by 1, while all the rest are still `0`. Now let's try to visit the names that start with `"T"` which are namely `"Two"` and `"Three"`.

```
>>> result = Watched.objects.visit(user__startswith='T')
>>> result
<QuerySet [<Watched: Watched object (2)>, <Watched: Watched object (3)>]>
>>> result.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'user': 'Two', 'count': 1}, {'id': 3, 'user': 'Three', 'count': 2}]>
>>> Watched.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'user': 'One', 'count': 1}, {'id': 2, 'user': 'Two', 'count': 1}, {'id': 3, 'user': 'Three', 'count': 2}, {'id': 4, 'user': 'Four', 'count': 0}, {'id': 5, 'user': 'Five', 'count': 1}, {'id': 6, 'user': 'Six', 'count': 0}]>
```

As you may notice, both records increased by 1, thus `"Three"` now has a count of `2` after being incremented twice.

Be aware that the side-effect of what you want to do (here implemented via the `WatchedManager.visit()` method) on an HTTP GET request means that there will be an update in the database (specifically the `Watched.count` field), which could be viewed as an anti-pattern since HTTP GET requests are meant to not perform updates.

Comment: The problem is not on how to increment the count attribute. My problem is on how to return the number of times ```Watched``` was hit per day. Example ```today_so_far = 30```. Here, 30 is the number of times ```Watched``` model has been hit today